# Whats the best way to make a performant "tags" grid list?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to achieve it through the `FlatList` and `VirtualizedList` components, which sadly brings up this warning:[image]

FlatList would work perfectly for what I want it for if only it would allow me to use `flexWrap: wrap`. Is there any way to achieve what I want with any other components?

I require view recycling to make sure everything stays performant as Il have up to 500 items in a list at a time. Ive seen various Grid View libraries but they arent suitable as they force you to specify a number of columns, I just want my tags (of variable width) to fit where they can aligned to the left.

Heres the code Im using for this example:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Component, FlatList } from 'react-native';

class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text
        style={styles.text}>
        {this.props.testing}
      </Text>
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    _renderItem = ({item}) => (
      <MyListItem
        testing={item}
      />
     );
     items = []
     for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
       items[i] = "asdi"+i
     }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={items}
          renderItem={_renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  list:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  text:{
    backgroundColor: "rgb(90, 90, 90)",
    marginBottom:10,
    margin:4,
    padding:5,
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```